# Insert new tag on index to html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Having html with table, I want to insert new table row (tag) with 'Toyota' on index 2 (between Audi and Mercedes).

I know how to update `trs` ResultSet, but don't know how to reflect it in returned html.

Here is my try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw_html = """<table border="0" class="df cars">
<thead>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
<th>Cars</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Audi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mercedes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BMW</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>"""

html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)

trs = html.find_all("tr")
trs.insert(2, f'<tr><td>Toyota</td></tr>')

return html
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to join together the string representation of the pieces:

```
return ''.join(map(str,trs))
```

Comment: Returned html has to stay as bs4.BeautifulSoup object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

- Create two new tags `<tr>` and `<td>` using the [`new_tag()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) method.
- Set the `text` of `<td>` to *Toyota* and Append the `<td>` tag to the `<tr>` tag.
- Since you need it at the 2nd position, first select the 1st `<td>` from `<tbody>` and insert the newly created `<td>` tag after this using [`.insert_after()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after).

Here is the complete code.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw_html = """<table border="0" class="df cars">
<thead>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
<th>Cars</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Audi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mercedes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BMW</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'lxml')

# Create a new <tr> tag
tr = soup.new_tag('tr')
# Create a new <td> tag
td = soup.new_tag('td')
# Text of <td> tag
td.string = 'Toyota'
# Append the <td> to <tr>
tr.append(td)

# Insert after the first <tr> of <tbody>
first_tr = soup.find('tbody').find('tr')

first_tr.insert_after(tr)
print(soup.prettify())
```

The newly created `<tr>` is added to the HTML now.

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="0" class="df cars">
   <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
     <th>
      Cars
     </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      Audi
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      Toyota
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      Mercedes
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      BMW
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```